# Find a specific line and replace it with a new one?

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I have a .php file that contains array data like below:

```
$config['setting_one'] = true;
$config['setting_two'] = "some string";
$config['setting_three']['option1'] = "some string";
```

What is the correct way to find the line starts with `$config['setting_two']` and replace the line with `$config['setting_two'] = "new string";` (new string will come from a post value).

Comment: You have a missing quote on one of your lines: `$config['setting_three']['option1'] = "some string"`

Comment: -1 for reposting and ignoring the advise given. And those new answers here aren't useful references for any future user.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding a specific line in php with and replace the line with preg_replace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921136/finding-a-specific-line-in-php-with-and-replace-the-line-with-preg-replace)

Comment: @mario, it is not fair to give -1 rep before check it up. I deleted the old post before posting the new one. I just make a new post because I wanted to display he content of php file I am dealing with. Is it crime to look for better advise by writing a more proper question for it?

Comment: @Shaquin Trifonoff, thank you.

Comment: It's not fair either to delete and disregard the answers you already received. If you're unhappy with the state of your last question, you can (1) add additional information, (2) add a bounty. Reposting a *shortened* version is **not** acceptable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Editing PHP files for configuration via PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833237/editing-php-files-for-configuration-via-php)

Comment: @mario, you are right. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: @mario I would like to fix downvotes. Please tell me how. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to read the file line by line using [fgets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)

```
$config = array();

while(($line = fgets($handle, 4096) ) !== false) {
    $config[] = $line;
}
```

Comment: There's a [`file()`](http://php.net/file) function, which does exactly that.

Answer (score 4):

There is no correct way.

The correct way is "don't do that".

You include the php code, and then update the variable by simply setting it.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am building a web admin panel for a project, I want to change these config values after getting posted preference.

Comment: in example, when I get a post value tells what's the new value  setting_two, I need to find this line in php file and replace it all with new value.

Comment: Is this file user editable? Because if so your parser needs to handle the full PHP grammar (which is more complicated). If not you could probably get away with search and replace on the array key name. A better way might be to generate the file from scratch every time. Do you need to display these values to the user so he can edit them? Because if so, and the user can edit the file they could put in some some code there that could mess things up. Answer my two questions and I'll give you a better answer.

Comment: yes the file is editable. Users will post some given values or string and I will find the line in php file and replace its value.

Comment: @yahyaE OK, if the file is user editable then you MUST NOT try to replace the line. Instead, load the file in PHP using `include()`. Make whatever change you need to the `$config` variable. Then write out the file from scratch. But be VERY VERY careful! Since the user can edit the file they can put any code they want in there, including code to completely obliterate any security you have.